# Как при помощи JFileChooser выбрать файл ,а путь к файлу отобразился в JtextField после закрытия диалогового окна

Tags: java, swing

Как при помощи `JFileChooser` выбрать файл и вернуть путь к файлу в `JTextField`?

```
JFileChooser d= new JFileChooser();
d.showOpenDialog(this);
File f = d.getSelectedFile();
```

Код показывает окно выбора файла.
А задача дальше, отобразить весь путь к файлу в `JTextField`.

Answer (score 0):

Как то так:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class JFileDialogTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() ->
        {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("_________");
            JTextField textField = new JTextField();
            JButton button = new JButton("Select file");
            button.addActionListener(e -> {
                JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
                int res = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(frame);
                if (res == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    textField.setText(fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
                }
            });
            frame.add(textField, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            frame.add(button, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setSize(300, frame.getHeight());
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

UPD по вопросу из комментария:
Вам необходимо откорректировать класс так:

```
public static class ClassXmlTest implements ActionListener {
    private JTextField f11;
    private JTextField f22;

    public ClassXmlTest(JTextField f11, JTextField f22) {
        this.f11 = f11;
        this.f22 = f22;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        File xmlFile = new File(f11.getText());
        File txtFile = new File(f22.getText());
        try {
            transform(xmlFile, txtFile);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

тогда действие будете делать так:

```
button2.addActionListener(new ClassXmlTest(f1, f2));
```

Comment: Спасибо,попробую!

Comment: Добрый день !Применяю ваш вариант ответа и не пойму почему на button2 не прикрепляется действие?В чем ошибка?

Comment: IDE подчеркивает, что Вы используете не статический класс в статическом методе main. Вам необходимо немного по другому построить Ваш код.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказки!Буду пробовать!

Answer (score 0):

Применяю ваш пример ко всей программе и никак не могу понять,что нужно!Хочу на кнопку button2 прикрепить ActionListener  и не получается!Где ошибка?`

```
public class JFileDialogTest {
    private JButton button2 = new JButton();
    private JFrame d = new JFrame("Конвертер RPC");
    private JTextField f1 = new JTextField(25);
    private JTextField f2 = new JTextField(25);
                 
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() ->
            {
                JFrame d = new JFrame("Конвертер RPC");
                //JTextField textField = new JTextField();
              JTextField f1 = new JTextField(25);
              JTextField f2 = new JTextField(25); 
             
                JButton button = new JButton("Выбрать");
                 JButton button1 = new JButton("Сохранить");
                 JButton button2 = new JButton("Конвертировать");
                   Component L1 = new JLabel("Файл xml");
                   Component L2 = new JLabel("Файл txt");
                
                button.addActionListener(e -> {
                    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
                    int res = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(d);
                    if (res == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                        f1.setText(fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
                    }
                });
                
                
                button1.addActionListener(e -> {
                    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
                 //   FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("txt");
                   // fileChooser.setFileFilter(filter);
                    int res = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(d);
                    if (res == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                        f2.setText(fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
                    }
                });  
               ActionListener act = new jfiledialogtest.ClassXmlTest();                
                button2.addActionListener(act);       
                                           
                
                 Container contentPane1 = d.getContentPane();
                 SpringLayout layout = new SpringLayout();
                 contentPane1.setLayout(layout);
                 contentPane1.add(f1);
                 contentPane1.add(f2);
                 contentPane1.add(button);
                 contentPane1.add(button1);
                 contentPane1.add(button2);
                  contentPane1.add(L1);
                  contentPane1.add(L2);
                  
                 
                  
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST , f1, 10, 
                             SpringLayout.WEST , contentPane1);
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, f1, 55, 
                             SpringLayout.NORTH, contentPane1);
     //   layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, f2, 25, 
       //                      SpringLayout.NORTH, contentPane1);
        //layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST , f1, 120, 
         //                    SpringLayout.EAST , f1      );
        
         layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST , f2, 10, 
                             SpringLayout.WEST , contentPane1);
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, f2, 150, 
                             SpringLayout.NORTH, contentPane1);
        //layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, f2, 75, 
          //                   SpringLayout.NORTH, contentPane1);
        //layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST , f2, 120, 
         //                    SpringLayout.EAST , f1      );
        
         layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST , button, 320, 
                             SpringLayout.WEST , contentPane1);
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, button, 50, 
                             SpringLayout.NORTH, contentPane1);
        
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST , button1, 320, 
                             SpringLayout.WEST , contentPane1);
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, button1, 145, 
                             SpringLayout.NORTH, contentPane1);
        
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST , button2, 150, 
                             SpringLayout.WEST , contentPane1);
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, button2, 250, 
                             SpringLayout.NORTH, contentPane1);
        
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST , L1, 10, 
                             SpringLayout.WEST , contentPane1);
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, L1, 40, 
                             SpringLayout.NORTH, contentPane1);
        
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST , L2, 10, 
                             SpringLayout.WEST , contentPane1);
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, L2, 135, 
                             SpringLayout.NORTH, contentPane1);     
        
        
                             
        
              //  d.add(f1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
               // d.add(button, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                //d.pack();
                d.setSize(450, 350);
                d.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                d.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                d.setVisible(true);
              
            });
                
               //ActionListener act = new JFileDialogTest.ClassXmlTest();                
               //button2.addActionListener(act);
             
    }

    public   class ClassXmlTest implements ActionListener {
            String str1 = f1.getText();
            String str2 = f2.getText();
       
       
        public ClassXmlTest() {            
             //String  str1 = f1.getText();
             //String str2 = f2.getText();
             
              File xmlFile = new File(str1);
             File txtFile = new File(str2);
            try {
                transform(xmlFile, txtFile);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();     
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           
            
                       
            
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }
    }

    public static void transform(File sourceXmlFile, File targetTxtFile) throws Exception {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        org.w3c.dom.Document doc =  dBuilder.parse(sourceXmlFile);
        // doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        org.w3c.dom.Node element = doc.getElementsByTagName("RPC").item(0);
        NodeList nodeList = element.getChildNodes();
        try (FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(targetTxtFile)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
                org.w3c.dom.Node node =  nodeList.item(i);
                String nodeName = node.getNodeName();
                String value = node.getTextContent();
                String lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
                switch (nodeName) {
                    case "nLineOff":
                        write(fileWriter, "LINE_OFF", value, "pixels"+ lineSeparator);
                        break;
                    case "nSampOff":
                        write(fileWriter, "SAMP_OFF", value, "pixels"+ lineSeparator);
                        break;
                    case "nLatOff":
                        write(fileWriter, "LAT_OFF", value, "degrees"+ lineSeparator);
                        break;
                    case "nLongOff":
                        write(fileWriter, "LONG_OFF", value, "degrees"+ lineSeparator);
                        break;
                    case "nHeightOff":
                        write(fileWriter, "HEIGHT_OFF", value, "meters"+ lineSeparator);
                        break;
                    case "nLineScale":
                        write(fileWriter, "LINE_SCALE", value, "pixels"+ lineSeparator);
                        break;
                    case "nSampScale":
                        write(fileWriter, "SAMP_SCALE", value, "pixels"+ lineSeparator);
                        break;
                    case "nLatScale":
                        write(fileWriter, "LAT_SCALE", value, "degrees"+ lineSeparator);
                        break;
                    case "nLongScale":
                        write(fileWriter, "LONG_SCALE", value, "degrees"+ lineSeparator);
                        break;
                    case "nHeightScale":
                        write(fileWriter, "HEIGHT_SCALE", value, "meters"+ lineSeparator);
                        break;
                    case "bLineNum":
                        String[] array1 = value.trim().split(",");
                        for (int c = 0; c < array1.length; c++) {
                            write(fileWriter, "LINE_NUM_COEFF_" + (c + 1), array1[c], ""+ lineSeparator);
                        }
                        break;
                    case "bLineDen":
                        String[] array2 = value.trim().split(",");
                        for (int c = 0; c < array2.length; c++) {
                            write(fileWriter, "LINE_DEN_COEFF_" + (c + 1), array2[c], ""+ lineSeparator);
                        }
                        break;
                    case "bSampNum":
                        String[] array3 = value.trim().split(",");
                        for (int c = 0; c < array3.length; c++) {
                            write(fileWriter, "SAMP_NUM_COEFF_" + (c + 1), array3[c], ""+ lineSeparator);
                        }
                        break;
                         case "bSampDen":
                        String[] array4 = value.trim().split(",");
                        for (int c = 0; c < array4.length; c++) {
                            write(fileWriter, "SAMP_DEN_COEFF_" + (c + 1), array4[c], ""+ lineSeparator);
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void write(FileWriter fileWriter, String name, String value, String what) throws 
        IOException {
        fileWriter.write(String.format("%s: %s %s\n", name, value, what));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
fc.setDialogTitle("Открыть файл"); // Заголовок
if(fc.showOpenDialog(this) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){ // showOpenDialog - будет кнопка с надписью "Open", showSaveDialog - "Save"
        textfield.setText(fc.getSelectedFile() + ""); // setText() - установить текст, getSelectedFile() - получить выбранный файл
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]